# IRC bot to auto-ban spammers in a room?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, bots, irc

I want to make an IRC bot to automatically join as a user in a IRC channel (in a webchat) and then stay online the bot to ban users who are spamming

What I need to start doing this? Which knowledges? some API maybe? Usage of Sockets?

Someone please can show me an example or introduce me?

I've found this code, I'm trying to examine all the things inside to try to understand but when I try to connect to the server it does not connet, it don't throw any exception just the user does not join in the room:

```
    Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

    Public Class My_IRC
        Private _sServer As String = String.Empty '-- IRC server name
        Private _sChannel As String = String.Empty '-- the channel you want to join (prefex with #)
        Private _sNickName As String = String.Empty '-- the nick name you want show up in the side bar
        Private _lPort As Int32 = 6667 '-- the port to connect to.  Default is 6667
        Private _bInvisible As Boolean = False '-- shows up as an invisible user.  Still working on this.
        Private _sRealName As String = "nodibot" '-- More naming
        Private _sUserName As String = "nodi_the_bot" '-- Unique name so of the IRC network has a unique handle to you regardless of the nickname.

        Private _tcpclientConnection As TcpClient = Nothing '-- main connection to the IRC network.
        Private _networkStream As NetworkStream = Nothing '-- break that connection down to a network stream.
        Private _streamWriter As StreamWriter = Nothing '-- provide a convenient access to writing commands.
        Private _streamReader As StreamReader = Nothing '-- provide a convenient access to reading commands.

        Public Sub New(ByVal server As String, ByVal channel As String, ByVal nickname As String, ByVal port As Int32, ByVal invisible As Boolean)
            _sServer = server
            _sChannel = channel
            _sNickName = nickname
            _lPort = port
            _bInvisible = invisible
        End Sub

        Public Sub Connect()

            '-- IDENT explained: 
            '-- -- When connecting to the IRC server they will send a response to your 113 port.  
            '-- -- It wants your user name and a response code back.  If you don't some servers 
            '-- -- won't let you in or will boot you.  Once verified it drastically speeds up 
            '-- -- the connecting time.
            '-- -- -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident
            '-- Heads up - when sending a command you need to flush the writer each time.  That's key.

            Dim sIsInvisible As String = String.Empty
            Dim sCommand As String = String.Empty '-- commands to process from the room.

            '-- objects used for the IDENT response.
            Dim identListener As TcpListener = Nothing
            Dim identClient As TcpClient = Nothing
            Dim identNetworkStream As NetworkStream = Nothing
            Dim identStreamReader As StreamReader = Nothing
            Dim identStreamWriter As StreamWriter = Nothing
            Dim identResponseString As String = String.Empty

            Try
                '-- Start the main connection to the IRC server.
                Console.WriteLine("**Creating Connection**")
                _tcpclientConnection = New TcpClient(_sServer, _lPort)
                _networkStream = _tcpclientConnection.GetStream
                _streamReader = New StreamReader(_networkStream)
                _streamWriter = New StreamWriter(_networkStream)

                '-- Yeah, questionable if this works all the time.
                If _bInvisible Then
                    sIsInvisible = 8
                Else
                    sIsInvisible = 0
                End If

                '-- Send in your information
                Console.WriteLine("**Setting up name**")
                _streamWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("USER {0} {1} * :{2}", _sUserName, sIsInvisible, _sRealName))
                _streamWriter.Flush()

                '-- Create your nickname.
                Console.WriteLine("**Setting Nickname**")
                _streamWriter.WriteLine(String.Format(String.Format("NICK {0}", _sNickName)))
                _streamWriter.Flush()

                '-- Tell the server you want to connect to a specific room.
                Console.WriteLine("**Joining Room**")
                _streamWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("JOIN {0}", _sChannel))
                _streamWriter.Flush()

                '-- By now the IDENT should be sent to your port 113.  Listen to it, grab the text, 
                '-- and send a response.
                '-- Idents are usually #### , ####
                '-- That is four digits, a space, a comma, and four more digits.  You need to send 
                '-- this back with your user name you connected with and your system.
                identListener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 113)
                identListener.Start()
                identClient = identListener.AcceptTcpClient
                identListener.Stop()
                Console.WriteLine("ident connection?")
                identNetworkStream = identClient.GetStream
                identStreamReader = New StreamReader(identNetworkStream)

                identResponseString = identStreamReader.ReadLine
                Console.WriteLine("ident got: " + identResponseString)
                identStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(identNetworkStream)
                '-- The general format for the IDENT response.  You can use UNIX, WINDOWS VISTA, WINDOWS XP, or what ever your system is.
                identStreamWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} : USERID : WINDOWS 7 : {1}", identResponseString, _sUserName))
                identStreamWriter.Flush()

                '-- By now you should be connected to your room and visible to anyone else.  
                '-- If you are receiving errors they are pretty explicit and you can maneuver 
                '-- to debuggin them.
                '-- 
                '-- What happens here is the command processing.  In an infinite loop the bot 
                '-- read in commands and act on them.
                While True
                    sCommand = _streamReader.ReadLine
                    Console.WriteLine(sCommand)

                    '-- Not the best method but for the time being it works.  
                    '-- 
                    '-- Example of a command it picks up
                    ' :nodi123!nodi12312@ipxxx-xx.net PRIVMSG #nodi123_test :? hola!
                    '-- You can extend the program to better read the lines!
                    Dim sCommandParts(sCommand.Split(" ").Length) As String
                    sCommandParts = sCommand.Split(" ")

                    '-- Occasionally the IRC server will ping the app.  If it doesn't respond in an 
                    '-- appropriate amount of time the connection is closed.
                    '-- How does one respond to a ping, but with a pong! (and the hash it sends)
                    If sCommandParts(0) = "PING" Then
                        Dim sPing As String = String.Empty
                        For i As Int32 = 1 To sCommandParts.Length - 1
                            sPing += sCommandParts(i) + " "
                        Next
                        _streamWriter.WriteLine("PONG " + sPing)
                        _streamWriter.Flush()
                        Console.WriteLine("PONG " + sPing)
                    End If

                    '-- With my jank split command we want to look for specific commands sent and react to them!
                    '-- In theory this should be dumped to a method, but for this small tutorial you can see them here.
                    '-- Also any user can input this.  If you want to respond to commands from you only you would 
                    '-- have to extend the program to look for your non-bot-id in the sCommandParts(0)
                    If sCommandParts.Length >= 4 Then
                        '-- If a statement is proceeded by a question mark (the semi colon's there automatically) 
                        '-- then repeat the rest of the string!
                        If sCommandParts(3).StartsWith(":?") Then
                            Dim sVal As String = String.Empty
                            Dim sOut As String = String.Empty
                            '-- the text might have other spaces in them so concatenate the rest of the parts 
                            '-- because it's all text.
                            For i As Int32 = 3 To sCommandParts.Length - 1
                                sVal += sCommandParts(i)
                                sVal += " "
                            Next
                            '-- remove the :? part.
                            sVal = sVal.Substring(2, sVal.Length - 2)
                            '-- Trim for good measure.
                            sVal = sVal.Trim
                            '-- Send the text back out.  The format is they command to send the text and the room you are in.
                            sOut = String.Format("PRIVMSG {0} : You said '{1}'", _sChannel, sVal)
                            _streamWriter.WriteLine(sOut)
                            _streamWriter.Flush()
                        End If
                        '-- If you don't quit the bot correctly the connection will be active until a ping/pong is failed.  
                        '-- Even if your programming isn't running!
                        '-- To stop that here's a command to have the bot quit!
                        If sCommandParts(3).Contains(":!Q") Then
                            ' Stop
                            _streamWriter.WriteLine("QUIT")
                            _streamWriter.Flush()
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    End If
                End While

            Catch ex As Exception
                '-- Any exception quits the bot gracefully.
                Console.WriteLine("Error in Connecting.  " + ex.Message)
                _streamWriter.WriteLine("QUIT")
                _streamWriter.Flush()
            Finally
                '-- close your connections
                _streamReader.Dispose()
                _streamWriter.Dispose()
                _networkStream.Dispose()
            End Try

        End Sub
    End Class

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim a As New My_IRC("irc.freenode.org", "#ircehn", "Elektro_bot", 6667, False)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using low level TCP communication, take a look at this [IRC Library](http://thresher.sourceforge.net/). It makes writing IRC software in managed .NET code a lot easier, including channel and users manipulation.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to use that library but I can't find any example in VBNET, also I can't understand too much C# code and the online translators will fail to convert the oficial C# examples. can you give a example of how to connect to a server and listen messages?

Comment: I have found a VBNEt example